The specific form of isomorphism from linear space $V$ to dual space $V*$
For a linear space $V$, we know that it is isomorphic to the dual space $V^*$, because they are both $n$-dimensional linear spaces.
But what exactly this isomorphic mapping looks like seems to be uncertain?
Is there an isomorphism from $V$ to $V^*$ such that for any given set of basis on $V^*$, one can find the basis in $V$ that is dual to it?
Here's an example (I'm not sure if it's correct):
Let $V=P_n=\text{span}\{1,t,\cdots,t^{n-1}\}$ be an $n$-dimensional real polynomial space of degree $\leq n<1$. Define mapping $f_\lambda:\varphi\mapsto\varphi(\lambda)$. At each point $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the polynomial
\begin{gather}\varphi(\lambda)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\varphi_i \lambda^i\end{gather}
corresponds to its value at that point . By changing $\lambda$, the basis of the dual space $V^*$ can be obtained:
According to the definition, directly set
\begin{gather}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_if_{\lambda_i}=0.\end{gather}
Expand and rearrange
\begin{gather}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\varphi_k\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i\lambda_i^k=0.
\end{gather}
So we only need to find a way to get $\lambda_{0},\cdots,\lambda_{n-1}$ so that $x_0=\cdots=x_{n-1}=0$. Examine linearity equation set
\begin{gather}
   \begin{pmatrix}
         1&1&\cdots&1\\
         \lambda_0&\lambda_1&\cdots&\lambda_{n-1}\\
         \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
         \lambda_0^{n-1}&\lambda_0^{n-1}&\cdots&\lambda_{n-1}^{n-1}
     \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
         x_0\\
         x_1\\
         \vdots\\
         x_{n-1}
     \end{pmatrix}=0.
    \end{gather}
Just let the system of equations have only 0 solutions. That is, the determinant of the coefficient matrix is not equal to 0. At the same time, note that the determinant of the coefficient matrix is the Vandermonde determinant, so only the value of the determinant is
\begin{gather}\prod_{0\leq i\leq j\leq n-1}(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)\neq 0.\end{gather}
Therefore, we only need to ensure that the values of any two $\lambda_i$ in $\lambda_i,i=0,1,\cdots,n-1$ are not equal.
It can be seen that by transforming $\lambda$ in this way, many bases on $V^*$ can be found, but it seems to be very difficult to find their dual bases in $V$?

Short answer: there is no natural way to choose a particular isomorphism between $V$ and its dual. There is a natural way to choose one between $V$ and the dual of its dual. (There is a precise way to define "natural" in this context.)

I don't understand your question. Isn't the dual base simply and explicitly given by $\operatorname{Hom}(R^n,R)=\prod_n\operatorname{Hom}(R,R)$?

The usual definition of dual basis says that if $(v_1^, \dots, v_n^)$ is dual to $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ then the dual to $(2v_1, \dots, 2v_n)$ is $(\frac12 v_1^, \dots, \frac12 v_n^)$. But if a linear map takes $v_i$ to $v_i^$, it takes $2v_1$ to $2v_1^$. Is this the obstruction you're looking for?

Throughout, for a matrix $A$, we let $A^i_j$ denote the row $i$, column $j$ entry of $A$.
Fix any basis $(b^1,b^2,\ldots, b^n)$ for $X$. Let $(f_1,\ldots, f_n)$ be a basis for $X^*$. Let $$E=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(b^1) & f_2(b^1) & \ldots & f_n(b^1) \\ f_1(b^2) & f_2(b^2) & \ldots & f_n(b^2) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ f_1(b^n) & f_2(b^n) & \ldots & f_n(b^n)\end{pmatrix}.$$

The matrix $E$ is invertible.

If it were not invertible, then there would be some non-zero vector $a=\begin{pmatrix} a^1 \\ a^2 \\ \vdots \\ a^n\end{pmatrix}$ such that $Ea=0$. Let $f=\sum_{j=1}^n a^jf_j$.  Note that the row $i$ entry of $Ea$ is $0$, since $Ea=0$, but also  $$\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(b^i)a^j=\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^n a^jf_j\Bigr)(b^i)=f(b^i).$$ Since this holds for all $i$, $f$ is the zero functional. But this is a contradiction, because $a$ is not the zero vector and $(f_1,\ldots, f_n)$ is a basis. So $E$ is invertible.
Let $F=E^{-1}$. Define $$g^i=\sum_{j=1}^n F_j^i b^j.$$
Fix $1\leqslant i,k\leqslant n$ and note that \begin{align*} f_i(g^k) & = f_i\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^n F_j^k b^j\Bigr)=\sum_{j=1}^n F_j^k E^i_i = [FE]^k_i \\ & = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & : i = k \\ 0 & : i \neq k.\end{array}\right. \end{align*}
Therefore for any basis of $X^*$, we evaluate against our fixed basis of $X$, invert the evaluation matrix, and read off the coefficients from the inverse for how to transform our fixed basis of $X$ into the dual basis of $X^*$.
